# Register a user into my database

Tags: php, facebook, api, oauth

I have an app which works fine, but slow on start up.  I have noticed that all other apps main page is index.php where as my index.php is a page to check if registered in my db and if not add to my db.

I am assuming they have a redirect in the Auth section, to check if registered into their db.  I'm not sure how to go about this.

Am i right in thinking they use the OAuth to register to their own DB? if this is a yes does anyone have a link that explains this and how to do it??

Comment: Sorry about that didn't realise it was so vague, updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth has nothing to do with saving data to a database. OAuth is protocol for authenticating a user with a website, without the need for revealing their username / password to the third-party site.

How you save the data to your DB is up to you. Most people will have some sort of database back-end (e.g. MySQL), and save the data using a Query. You would first need to retrieve the data from Facebook (using Graph API and calling /me) and then inserting the data into the DB.

Simply using OAuth will not achieve any of the above. You will still need to get the data and then save the data. OAuth will only provide you with access to obtain the data you want to save.

Comment: ah okay just wanted to know my limitations, that i had, at the moment my set up is a file that check and registers and re-directs to my main page, what set up would you recommend?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to do a redirect. You should check if the user is logged in first (ask them to login otherwise), then check if the user exists in the DB (add them if now). You can just show the content on the main page since saving the user's data only takes a few microseconds. Why was the user's time with a needless redirect?

Comment: ahh i see, ill look into doing it that way